# How can I show $\overline{X}=X\cup\partial X$ using the definition $\partial X=\overline{X}\cap \overline{X^c}$?

Tags: metric-spaces

$\overline{X}=X\cup\partial X$

I'm stuck in this problem. That is the definition of boundary I should use:

$\partial X=\overline{X}\cap \overline{X^c}$

Comment: your definition of a boundary is the empty set.

Comment: $\partial X = \bar{X} \cap \bar{(X^c)}$ the "()" makes the diferency, Sorry.

Comment: Small latex tip: In order to denote the closure of the complement of $X$, use \overline{X^c} instead of \bar{X^c}. The former is clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I edited.

Comment: Have you tried substituting in the definition of a boundary and then used the distributive property of sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $"\supseteq"$ follows from $X \subseteq \overline{X}$ and $\partial X= \overline{X} \cap \overline{X^c} \subseteq \overline{X}$.

For the reverse inclusion we take $x\in \overline{X}$. If it is in $X$, then we are happy. On the other hand, if $x\in \overline{X} \setminus X$, then we need to show that $x\in \partial X$. We already have $x\in \overline{X}$, so we are left to show that $x\in \overline{X^c}$. This follows from $x\in X^c \subseteq \overline{X^c}$.